# Seaborn's histplot doesn't match Matplotlib's hist when using log_scale=True

Tags: python, scipy, distribution, scipy.stats

I'm probably making a stupid mistake, but here's how to reproduce:

1. Generate random variables based on log-normal distribution
2. Fit a log-normal distribution to the synthetic data
3. Compute the probability distribution function using the fitted parameters
4. Plot histogram of synthetic variables overlaid with the PDF
5. They don't match!

```py
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import lognorm
import numpy as np

mu = 25
samples = lognorm.rvs(s=1, loc=0, scale=np.log(mu), size=10000)
shape, loc, scale = lognorm.fit(samples)
print(shape, loc, scale)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.histplot(samples, bins=50, stat="density", log_scale=True, ax=ax)
xs = np.linspace(0.1, 100, 10000)
ys = lognorm.pdf(xs, s=shape, loc=loc, scale=scale)
ax.plot(xs, ys, "r-")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with `scipy.stats`. Plotting with `matplotlib`, I see good agreement:

```py
from scipy.stats import lognorm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu = 25
sample = lognorm.rvs(s=1, loc=0, scale=np.log(mu), size=100000)
shape, loc, scale = lognorm.fit(sample)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xscale('log')
bins = np.logspace(-2, 2)
ax.hist(sample, bins=bins, density=True)
xs = np.logspace(-2, 2, 1000)
ys = lognorm.pdf(xs, s=shape, loc=loc, scale=scale)
ax.plot(xs, ys, "r-")
```

[image]

You can also plot the histogram of the log of the sample against the corresponding normal distribution with Seaborn.

```py
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import lognorm, norm
import numpy as np

mu = 25
sample = lognorm.rvs(s=1, loc=0, scale=np.log(mu), size=100000)
shape, loc, scale = lognorm.fit(sample)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.histplot(np.log(sample), bins=50, stat="density", ax=ax)
xs = np.linspace(-2, 5, 1000)
ys = norm.pdf(xs, loc=np.log(np.log(mu)), scale=1)
ax.plot(xs, ys, "r-")
```

[image]

I suspect there's something about the interaction between `'density'` and `log_scale` that is not correct, possibly in our understanding of seaborn.

*Update: see https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3579 for an explanation of what is going on. Apparently the density normalization is performed on the log-transformed data, even though the data is displayed with the original magnitudes on a log-scaled axis.*

*If the shape of the seaborn histogram were preserved but the log-scaled axis were replaced by a linear-scaled axis with log-transformed labels, then the area under the curve would be 1.0.*

*In other words, it can be thought of as a histogram of the log-transformed data but displayed with the original data magnitudes on a log-scaled axis.*

---

This doesn't account for the problem, but noticed that you defined `mu=25` and passed `scale=np.log(mu)` to `lognorm`. Double check that this is what you mean to do against the [documentation of `lognorm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html).

> Suppose a normally distributed random variable `X` has mean `mu` and standard deviation `sigma`. Then `Y = exp(X)` is lognormally distributed with `s = sigma` and `scale = exp(mu)`.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure what's going on with Seaborn's `histplot`. Any idea?

Comment: It might be worth checking out the `histplot` source or filing an issue with seaborn (https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues). Looking at your seaborn plot between 10^1 and 2*10^1 (10 to 20), the minimum height of the bar is 0.1, so i think the probablility mass just in that portion is at least 1.0. It's not obvious to me what it's doing, and if it's not a bug, the documentation could be improved.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! For future reference, just opened up an issue with seaborn: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3579. Re `np.log(mu)`: you're correct, I didn't mean to pass the log, should have been just `mu`. (I think there's a typo in your answer, should have been `samples` instead of `sample`)

Comment: Oops. Thanks for catching that. I meant to quietly promote the exclusive use of "sample" as "set of observations" rather than using it both to mean "observation" and "set of observations".

Comment: No worries, for the sake of high-quality training data for future GPTs :) In case you were interested in following up: I updated the issue tracker. TLDR; it seems that Matplotlib's hist does a weighted average (due to non-uniform dx) when plotting histogram with `density=True`, whereas Seaborn doesn't. This leads to an interesting consequence: the peak of Matplotlib's histogram shifts, whereas Seaborn remains the same! Would appreciate it if you could comment on the issue tracker on which one you think is more plausible. Thanks again!